# proper cancel with fine-uploader core

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

i'm trying to implement a multiple uploader with fine-uploader. I'm building my own UI for it.
Basically it works as intended (selecting multiple files -> upload just fine)
But when I do:

1. add file1
2. add file2
3. delete file2 (call to cancel(id)) -> status changes to cancelled
4. add file3

first file is getting uploaded, but then i get an exception:
Error: [Fine Uploader 5.11.8] 1 is not a valid file ID to upload! (which referes to the deleted/cancelled file)
third file is not uploaded anymore.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $messages = $('#messages');
    $("#uploader").fineUploader({
        uploaderType: 'basic',
        element: $('#uploader'),
        button: $('.img-upload-button'),
        debug: true,
        autoUpload: false,
        multiple: true,
        sizeLimit: 209715200,
        request: {
            endpoint: '/handler?action.uploadImage'
        }
    }).on('submit', function(event, id, fileName) {
        $messages.html('<div id="file-' + id + '" class="alert" style="margin: 20px 0 0">onSubmit</div>');
        addBlock(id, fileName);
    }).on('upload', function(event, id, fileName) {
        $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info').html('<img src="/custom/img/fine-uploader/loading.gif" alt="Initializing. Please hold." style="width: auto;"> ' + 'Initializing ' + '“' + fileName + '”');
    }).on('progress', function(event, id, fileName, loaded, total) {
        console.log('progress: ' + loaded);
        if (loaded < total) {
            progress = Math.round(loaded / total * 100) + '% of ' + Math.round(total / 1024) + ' kB';
            $('#file-' + id).removeClass('alert-info').html('<img src="/custom/img/fine-uploader/loading.gif" alt="In progress. Please hold."> ' + 'Uploading ' + '“' + fileName + '” ' + progress);
        } else {
            $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info').html('<img src="/custom/img/fine-uploader/loading.gif" alt="Saving. Please hold."> ' + 'Saving ' + '“' + fileName + '”');
        }
    }).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
        console.log('ID: '+id);
        console.log('fileName: '+fileName);
        if (responseJSON.success === true) {
            $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info').html('<div>success</div>');
        } else {
            $('#file-' + id).addClass('alert-info').html('<div>fail</div>');
        }
    }).on('cancel', function(event, id, fileName) {
        $('.block' + id).remove();
    });
```

EDIT:
with button handler:

```
function addBlock(id, fileName) {
    // inserts a file representation block dynamically
    ... 
    insert button: <input class="img-delete" type="button" value="delete" data="' + id + '">
    ...
    $('.file-list').on("click", ".img-delete", cancelBlock);
}
function cancelBlock() {
    // removes a cancelled block
    var id = $(this).attr("data");
    $("#uploader").fineUploader('cancel', id);
}

$('#trigger-upload').click(function() {
    $('#uploader').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
});
```

the cancelled block is removed correctly and status update on file id to cancel is also fine.

any hints on what am I missing?

- core
- traditional endpoint
- v5.11.8
- jquery 2.2

Comment: You'll need to show the code that attempts to cancel the upload, since that is where your problem lies.

Comment: hello @RayNicholus, i've edited my post. thx for looking at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine Uploader's API expects IDs to be a number. Let's look at your call to the [`cancel` method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#cancel):

```
function cancelBlock() {
    // removes a cancelled block
    var id = $(this).attr("data");
    $("#uploader").fineUploader('cancel', id);
}
```

jQuery's `attr` method always returns a string. Again, Fine Uploader IDs are numbers. You can cast this string to a number using `parseInt()`. To fix this issue, your `cancelBlock` method should look like this instead:

```
function cancelBlock() {
    // removes a cancelled block
    var id = parseInt($(this).attr("data"));
    $("#uploader").fineUploader('cancel', id);
}
```

Also, please consider abandoning jQuery, especially when using Fine Uploader. There is absolutely [no benefit to using Fine Uploader's jQuery wrapper](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1310), and [very little benefit to using jQuery elsewhere, given the advancements in JavaScript and the web API](https://amzn.com/1484222342).

Comment: thx Ray, works fine. yes, i read about no-benefit of jQuery, but since jquery is involved in the project anyway, i want to keep it this way.